# Mongoose Reconnect Event is Not getting fired after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Mongoose 'reconnected' Event is not fired after 'close' event is getting fired after the second time. How can I increase the time to always retry?

close: Emitted after we disconnected and onClose (after this, if I start Mongo, it is not firing any event) executed on all of this connections models.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer for this, We need to use the server options of mongodb-native driver options like this.

```
var opts = {
server: {
      auto_reconnect: true,
      reconnectInterval: 5000,
      reconnectTries: Infinity,
      socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: 1,
        connectTimeoutMS: 10000
      }
    }
}
```

For more options follow this document: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Server.html